# How to interpret output of nmblookup -A

Tags: linux, samba, domain

The command

```
  nmblookup -A IP_address
```

returns, according to the *man page*, a *node status query* on this address. A typical output is:

```
  Looking up status of 192.168.253.101
    HPB4B52F0559C2  <00> -         B <ACTIVE> <PERMANENT> 
    MSHOME          <00> - <GROUP> B <ACTIVE> <PERMANENT> 
    HPB4B52F0559C2  <20> -         B <ACTIVE> <PERMANENT> 
    HP0559C2        <00> -         B <ACTIVE> <PERMANENT> 
    HP0559C2        <20> -         B <ACTIVE> <PERMANENT>
```

I have been unable to understand the meaning of this output in detail. For instance, what do the different lines correspond to? The numbers within *<>*? The B code (could also be M or H)? The keywords ACTIVE and PERMANENT?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each line corresponds to a *name* that the node has claimed using NetBIOS.

- The first field is the name itself.
- The second field is the [suffix](http://ubiqx.org/cifs/Appendix-C.html), or the 16th byte of the name, in hexadecimal. It shows the *type* of this name – `0x00` is "Workstation" (a regular NetBIOS node), `0x20` is "Server" (a node running a SMB file server), `0x01` is "[Browser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751403.aspx)" (a node that keeps track of all NetBIOS names on the network), `0x03` is "[Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Messenger_service)" (a node *or a user* that can receive popup notifications), and so on, and so on.
- The third field is unknown to me yet...
- The fourth field marks this line as a "group" name – one that multiple node (AFAIK up to 16) may claim at once. In this case, a group name of type `0x00` (Workstation) denotes the *workgroup* that the node is in (which again has to do with [network browsing](http://ubiqx.org/cifs/Browsing.html)).
- The fifth field is the [node type](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/119493) (though I don't know why it is a property of each name – AFAIK, it is a setting of the node itself…) – B-nodes use NetBIOS datagrams which are broadcast in the LAN; P-nodes (point-to-point) use a central WINS server; M-nodes (mixed) first try broadcast then WINS when resolving names; H-nodes (hybrid), a later improvement over M-node, first try WINS then broadcast (this is a little faster).
- I am not sure of the last two fields. It's likely that `<ACTIVE>` means that the node successfully registered this name; if it ended up a duplicate, it would still be listed in response to a status query, but it would have a different marker. Similarly, `<PERMANENT>` is likely to mean that the name doesn't expire, or something.

Further reading:

- The chapter "[Browse Service](http://ubiqx.org/cifs/Browsing.html)" from "Implementing CIFS" describes network browsing and name types in detail.

Edits welcome.

Comment: Very good answer indeed, thank you for taking the time.